# ConvertTo-Html is not displaying data correctly

Tags: powershell

I have a very simple script where I am listing all the websites on my server. I am using this output to create custom columns in `Format-Table` to show required information. Then I want to represent this whole info in a HTML file using `ConvertTo-Html` cmdlet.

But when I run below code, it just creates garbage. However, if I do an `Out-File` to a .txt (no HTML conversion), it records correct information. Also, if I only display the results on screen, it still shows correct information.

```cs
cls
Import-Module WebAdministration
Get-Website |
  Format-Table @{n = 'Site_Name'; e = {$_.Name}},
    @{n = 'Physical Path'; e = {$_.physicalpath}},
    @{n = 'Version'; e = {($_.physicalpath.split("\"))[-1]}} -AutoSize |
  ConvertTo-Html |
  Out-File -FilePath D:\test.html
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Format-Table` creates formatted output that is suitable for displaying it in the console, but not for passing it to `ConvertTo-Html`.

Replace `Format-Table` with `Select-Object`:

```
Get-Website |
  Select-Object @{n='Site_Name';e={$_.Name}},
    @{n='Physical Path';e={$_.physicalpath}},
    @{n='Version';e={($_.physicalpath.split("\"))[-1]}} |
  ConvertTo-Html |
  Out-File -FilePath D:\test.html
```

and the problem will disappear.

You can see the difference if you pass the `Format-Table` and the `Select-Object` output into `Get-Member`:

```
... | Format-Table ... -AutoSize | Get-Member
... | Select-Object ... | Get-Member
```

Comment: Hi Ansgar,
Many thanks for taking out time to provide me with an answer and correcting my post.
I do have one question though (still new to powershell), can I somehow resize the columns using `Select-Object` cmdlet. My goal is to have this job run as a scheduled post-deployment task to retrieve versions for all websites hosted and I wanted to display it in a nicely formatted table in a html file.